Rails not injecting turbo_stream in header
The turbo handbookindicates it will send in the header the following:
Content-Type: text/vnd.turbo-stream.html
The application was running as expected up to a point.  After installing gem prosopite, where some analysis of N+1 queries generated some controller method changes.  But now, an unmodified
<%= button_to cover_recipes_path do %>
  <%= fa_icon('plus-circle', class: 'fa') %>
<% end %>

get processed as:
Processing by CoverRecipesController#create as HTML
adding to the controller action
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cover_recipe.save
        format.turbo_stream
      end
    end

is logged with the error:
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
Uninstalling prosopite does not change this behaviour.
Thus, turbo appears to have been disabled.  How can thie be remedied?

It turns out that this test was being conducted with Safari on MacOS that was deliberately kept on its version with which the model was built with.
Apple does not update Safari, if the system is not updated. Another manifestation of the silo effect.
Thus, not being a 'modern' browser, the processing reverted to HTML.  The Rails version is one devoid of the warning about modern browsers.
